# Download and upload 4k image in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to upload a 4k image in WordPress. Now the scene is when the user view the page the size of the image is small for fast loading and when they download image it should be in an original size i.e 4K

Answer (score 2):

- Upload 4k image using media menu on admin dashboard.
- Take the image URL just clicking the recently uploaded image.
- Use image anywhere on any size you want.
- Then paste the URL as a link on image.